# Counting no of rows returned by a select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to count the no of rows which is returned by the following query.

```
select m.Company_id
from Monitor as m
    inner join Monitor_Request as mr on mr.Company_ID=m.Company_id
    group by m.Company_id
    having COUNT(m.Monitor_id)>=5
```

I have tried with following

```
select COUNT(*) from
(
select m.Company_id
from Monitor as m
    inner join Monitor_Request as mr on mr.Company_ID=m.Company_id
    group by m.Company_id
    having COUNT(m.Monitor_id)>=5)
```

It gives an error message in query analyzer which says the following:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Was `@@ROWCOUNT` ever considered?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

SQL Server requires subqueries that you `SELECT FROM` or `JOIN` to have an alias.

Add an alias to your subquery (in this case `x`):

```
select COUNT(*) from
(
select m.Company_id
from Monitor as m
    inner join Monitor_Request as mr on mr.Company_ID=m.Company_id
    group by m.Company_id
    having COUNT(m.Monitor_id)>=5)  x
```

Comment: It helps me lot..thnx

Comment: I wish there was a way to make it ignore ORDER BY errors...

Answer (score 16):

Try wrapping your entire select in brackets, then running a count(*) on that

```
select count(*)
from
(
   select m.id
   from Monitor as m 
    inner join Monitor_Request as mr 
       on mr.Company_ID=m.Company_id   group by m.Company_id
    having COUNT(m.Monitor_id)>=5
) myNewTable
```

Comment: It's just a madeup name, you can call it whatever you want. I guess a better name would be [MonitorRequestsWith5OrMoreMonitors]

Answer (score 7):

The syntax error is just due to a missing alias for the subquery:

```
select COUNT(*) from
(
select m.Company_id
from Monitor as m
    inner join Monitor_Request as mr on mr.Company_ID=m.Company_id
    group by m.Company_id
    having COUNT(m.Monitor_id)>=5)  mySubQuery  /* Alias */
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply needed to add the alias on the subquery AND ALSO you  need to add another on the returned column inside the subquery. If you don't add the second alias you'll get another error: wiggly line under the "mySubQuery  " with the message "No column was specified for column 1 to 'x'". give a name to the inside column and voila!

```
 select COUNT(*) from
    (
      select m.Company_id AS Company ID
        from Monitor as m
       inner join Monitor_Request as mr 
          on mr.Company_ID=m.Company_id
       group by m.Company_id
      having COUNT(m.Monitor_id)>=5  )  mySubQuery
```

Comment: How does this differ from JNK's accepted 2012 answer?