# SQL Query Optimization / Right Technique to do the thing (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I want to count the no. of records returned by a SQL query which is dynamic (user input)

So I do the following

```
select count(*) from (user query);
```

How to optimize this?

for example

```
select count(*) from (select name,unitprice,brand from product);
```

if product table has `> 100,000` records.

> NOTE: the user query can have a *group by* as well as an *order by*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting no of rows returned by a select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945755/counting-no-of-rows-returned-by-a-select-query)

Comment: An `order by` will cause problems. I think the workaround is to specify `select top 100 percent ...` or probably easier to just strip it out.

Comment: Your derived table will also need an alias, i.e,. something like `) as T;` on the end.

Comment: How is the presence of `GROUP BY` makes it any different?

Comment: use count(1) or count(name) instead of count(*), you get some performance improvement.

Comment: @Jisson That's a myth

Comment: @Jisson: That's utter nonsense. Counting rows is of course not slower than counting a value per row that shall be checked whether it is null. `COUNT(*)` would even be faster did not the optimizer see that `1` or `name` will never be null and simply perform a `COUNT(*)` internally..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need to run the user query but also want the count for something else.  `@@ROWCOUNT` is the built-in way to achieve this:

```
SELECT name, unitprice, brand, etc
FROM product
GROUP BY name, unitprice, brand, etc
ORDER BY name, etc;

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Depending on what you want to do with the count, you might want to put it in a variable to refer to it later, since `@@ROWCOUNT` only works for the last query executed:

```
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT int;
SELECT yourQuery;
SELECT @ROWCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT;

SELECT @ROWCOUNT;
```

Comment: the above solution works for me, but is it good if we have rows in terms of lakhs/millions?

Comment: and how to do it optimally in a single query

Comment: and can I count the number of rows wihtout actually executing the user query?
I mean before its execution.
Note: We can modify the user query as we like

Comment: @SahilKumarKansal `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` will return the number of rows from the last executed query instantly, regardless of how many rows there are.  If you want to execute the query anyway, it's the best option, because you won't have to execute the query, then RE-execute the query with a `SELECT COUNT(*)` just to get the count.  This allows for one execution instead of two.

Comment: There is no way to definitively count the number of rows without executing the query.  But if you hope to avoid executing the whole query, you can at least remove things such as `ORDER BY` which will have no effect on row count and will slow down most queries.  Then just do the `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (query) A` approach.